# Pass variable to context match awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract context from a file with `awk` from a start pattern until an end pattern.

Here is simplified sample input to reproduce:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
    
4
5
6
```

When I pass the start pattern `1` as follows it works:

```
$ awk '/1/,/^$/' file

1
2
3
```

But when I pass a variable as the start pattern I get no result:

```
$ awk -v var=1 '/var/,/^$/' file
```

Comment: See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable names are not expanded inside `//` in awk. So when you have `/var/`, awk will search for a `v` followed by an `a` and then an `r`. What you want is:

```
$  awk -v var=1 '$0~var,/^$/' file
1
2
3
```